# Не могу понять как конкретно работает return в java

Tags: java, методы, return

Не понимаю, зачем в `public int getAge()` нужно использовать `return`?

```
public class Puppy{

   int puppyAge;

   public Puppy(String name){
      System.out.println("Передаваемое имя:" + name ); 
   }
   public void setAge( int age ){
       puppyAge = age;
   }

   public int getAge( ){
       System.out.println("Возраст щенка:" + puppyAge ); 
       return puppyAge;
   }
   public static void main(String []args){
  Puppy myPuppy = new Puppy( "Багет" );

  myPuppy.setAge( 2 );

  myPuppy.getAge( );

      System.out.println("Значение переменной:" + myPuppy.puppyAge ); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Смотри... Вот у тебя есть два метода

```
 public void setAge( int age ){
       puppyAge = age;
   }

   public int getAge( ){
       System.out.println("Возраст щенка:" + puppyAge ); 
       return puppyAge;
   }
```

public **void** setAge() - означает, что при вызове - "возращать" ничего не надо, а просто код который будет внутри, просто отработает свое назначение(ключевое слово тут **void**)

public **int** getAge( ) - означает, что этот метод обязательно ждет, что ему в данном случае вернут число какое-то(ключевое слово **int**) для передачи числа используют **return**.

Ты можешь написать например так

```
 public String getName( )
```

тогда ты обязан будешь вернуть строку сюда

```
 public String getName( ) {
return "Мурзик";
}
```

И смотри как классно можно этим воспользоваться

```
 public static void main(String []args){
  Puppy myPuppy = new Puppy( "Багет" );
String name = myPuppy.getName();
System.out.println(name);
```

У тебя напечатается Мурзик))